# Property collections vs Repository methods (.NET)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, automapper, repository-pattern

I would like to know where I should define the retrieval of child collections.

I'm using automapper to map my EF entities to my business classes all within my repository.

**Scenario:**
I have a BookshelfRepository.
If I have a Bookshelf business class that has properties: color, brand, etc.
In the db I also have a books table where a Bookshelf can have multiple books.

**Should I:**
a) Create a method in my Bookshelf class called GetAllBooks() [ie. obviously only for that bookshelf]
b) Create a new repository for my books and create a method called GetBooksByBookshelf()
c) other...

Basically trying to figure out where to put my retrieval of my books. In the Bookshelf class or the Books repository.

Cheers mates

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for depends a lot on how you plan to load and use the data. That is, if you load a bookshelf entity, should it not have a Collection of books loaded? Are your books aware of the shelf of which they belong? Thinking through some of the ways you would plan to use the data should help you logically place the methods in the right location, and determine on which object you would want these properties. Question like:

Is bookshelf(ves) an attribute of a book, which I would want to know about an individual book when looking at it? Do books belong to multiple bookshelves?